# Chrome 32 - how to hide Console emulator feature

Tags: google-chrome, browser

Console emulator sounds cool but I really need to view the dom tree, css etc.
There's a setting in 'Overrides' to `show 'emulation' view in console drawer but this toggle doesn't persist.

How can I toggle it permanently?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it has some obnoxious auto-show feature when any feature of the emulator is enabled. Go through all of the blue checked options on the right and make sure everything is deselected. I just struggled with it for about 30 minutes and that fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @jiminy on this question worked for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819685/how-can-i-keep-the-console-drawer-hidden-by-default-every-time-i-open-chrome-d/25429506#25429506

Basically, the emulator toggle is highlighted blue when it's active and will open every time. If you click again and toggle it back to black, it will stay closed.